# Speed test in JMS 2.0

Tags: java, jms

I´m working on a web application project which use JMS. I want to Know how long a message takes to be delivered with a large number of clients. To do that I´m using a different package and a different class. There is few information about this, and I want to know which processes are normally used to know  this kind of information.

Comment: Too broad a question to really answer as so much will depend on overall architectures and choice of JMS provider

Answer (score 1):

This question is not specific to JMS, but is more of a "How do I load test a particular module in a Web application". Look at the load test tools, e.g. Tsung: http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/